# FileWriter and jar file - cannot find the resource

Tags: java, resources, jar

I wrote a program recently. The file processing class is the next:

```
package smartest.eu;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Processor {
    private BufferedWriter out;
    private BufferedReader in;

    // this method opens the file for reading!
    public void openWriter() throws Exception {
        if (out == null) {
            try {
                out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("src/personaldata.txt")));
            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new Exception("Writer opened already");
        }
    }

    // this method opens the reader
    public void readWriter() throws Exception {
        if (in == null) {
            try {
                in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/personaldata.txt"));
                in.mark(65538);
            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new Exception("Reader already opened");
        }
    }

    // this method reads the file line by line outputting a string as the result
    public String readText() throws Exception {
        String answer1 = "";
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                if ((answer1 = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    answer1 += "\n";
                }
                else {
                    answer1 = "No more data!\nThe stream will be read from the beginning!\n";
                }
            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new Exception("Open file for reading at first");
        }

        return answer1;
    }

    // this method writes the given string to a file
    public void writeText(String a) throws Exception {
        if (out != null) {
            out.write(a);
            out.flush();
        }
        else {
            throw new Exception("Open file for writing at first");
        }
    }

    public void resitStream() {
        try {
            in.reset();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

The directory structure processor.jar:

```
1) manifest
2) personaldata.txt
3) smartest/eu/*.class
```

But when I am making the jar file, it cannot find the file (gives "File not found exception"). How could I fix it? 
P.S. Could you also mention something to read on the problem - why .jar files are not available inside of jars?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line

```
new FileReader("src/personaldata.txt")
```

tries to open the file `personaldata.txt`, in a subdirectory `src` of the current directory. The current directory is the directory where you are when you launch the java command in your command prompt. So, if you're in `c:\` and launch `java -jar the/path/to/myJar.jar`, it will search for the file in c:\src\personaldata.txt.

File is thus used to access the file system. Not resources inside the jar. To load a resource from the classpath, you must use

```
Processor.class.getResourceAsStream("/personaldata.txt")
```

Look at the [javadoc of this method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) to understand how it works.

Note that writing to a file in the jar is impossible.